# Eclipse Validation not picking up any errors in XML file? How do I check XML?

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation

I am testing Eclipse for the first time and I purposefully made a number of minor errors to see if how Eclipse works. However, it doesn't seem to be picking anything up...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jobList>
<job status="unallocated">
    <resource employeeId="AD145267" type="Laptop">            
        <model>Vostro 1540</model>
        <manufacturer>Dell
        <serialNumber>764839211-19-H</seriaNumber>
        </manufacturer>         
    </resource>
    <problem reported="2012-01-22T15:23:00">Fails to boot</problem>
</job>

<job status="unallocated">
    <resource employeeId="TE135218" type="Wireless printer">
        <manufacturer>Epson</manufacturer>
        <model>Stylus SX435W</model>
        <serialNumber>E4356-982312</serialNumber>
    </resurce>
    <problem reported="2012-01-23T10:07:00">No wireless access</problem>
</job>

<job status="allotted">
    <resource type="Network drive">
        <manufacturer>G-Tech</manufacturer>
        <model>G-RAID Hard drive array</model>
        <serialNumber>783451287G</serialNumber>
    </resource>
    <problem>Read errors reported during rebuild</problem>

    <work jobId="564">
        <technician allocated="2012-01-24T15:05:00">T541</technician>
        <Note>Spoke to Eric about what happened.</Note>
        <nte>Ran phase 1 diagnostics - no errors reported</note>
    </work>
</job>

</jobList>
```

I've made a few mistakes like note and resource but when I right click on Eclipse, select validate it says that the validation completed with no errors or warnings... Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to test it? There doesn't seem to be a button to check XML?

Comment: Is this file in your workspace? Does its project have the Validation Builder on it (check the project's Validation page in its Properties dialog). Do you have the XML Editor installed and working?

Comment: @nitind all I've done is open the XML file with Eclipse which is displaying in workspace - think (but not in Project Explorer)... Yeah I have XML Editor working. 
I just tested an XML pre-set template through Project Explorer (checking project validation) and that did pick up errors... How do I add my files to a project? Or make a new project with my files? Do I copy files in the eclipse dir?

Comment: You can use the Import wizards from the file menu, or copy files into the workspace location from outside Eclipse and Refresh the workspace from the File menu afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Validation, along with most of the Validators contributed through the Validation Framework, is only supported for files located in and opened from the workspace.